# About Cocos2d Camera?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I am try to figure out the zoom in/out effect. I am using tile-mapping background.

```
[self.Camera setEyeX:eyeY:eyeZ:]
[self.Camera setCenterX:centerY:centerZ:]
[self.Camera setUpX:upY:upZ:]
```

I don't know what differences among these methods and what these coordinate arguments represents.
Can someone help me please.
Thanks and sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0):

It'll be a lot easier to just set tilemap.scale rather than using CCCamera.

The eye coordinates are the vector pointing in the direction the camera "looks at". The center coordinates are nothing more than the position of the camera in space. You can ignore the up vector, unless you want to rotate the camera's view. If I'm not mistaken, setting the up vector to (0, 1, 0) will ensure that the camera is not rotated and the coordinate system is what it should be (X extends to the right, Y extends upwards).